# Fibonacci in python cant run the code receiving syntax error or other

Tags: python

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcqDO.png)Im try to run this code to get fibonacci numbers in range 1-11

```
def fibonacci (n) :
  if n == 1  or n ==2
  return 1
return fibonacci (n-1)  + fibonacci(n-2)
for i in range (1,11):
  print (fibonacci (i))
```

but im getting :

```
**Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2
    if n == 1  or n ==2
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

In this video tutorial the guy doing the same-thing and getting result
i dont understand  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cz476EsH1Lc&t=3s 3:10

version is 2.7.6

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code.

Comment: You missed a `:` after `if`, it has to be `if n == 1 or n ==2:`.

Comment: add your code not an image of it and based on the image, there is quite a bit wrong indentation, missing colons....

Comment: @Gennady Kandaurov  now im getting:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 3
    return 0
         ^
IndentationError: expected an indented bloc

Comment: You're getting "expected an indented block" because the code following the `if` needs to be indented, just like the code in the scope of the `for` loop is indented.  Please take a python tutorial.  At StackOverflow we love to help, but we don't expect to have to teach the day 1 basics of a language.

Comment: I'm going to recommend that this question be closed.  The idea of SO is to create an encyclopedia of questions and answers.  This post won't be helpful as part of that encyclopedia.  Please don't take it personally, and when you have a specific question, come back and ask.

Answer (score 3):

If you've copied your code exactly (besides formatting – indentation is very important in python) then the problem is the missing `:` after `n==2`.

It should look something like this:

```
def fibonacci (n):
    if n == 1 or n == 2: # the colon is missing here.
        return 1
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error is stating that you missed `:` in the `if` statement. Also your indentation is not correct.

```
if n == 1 or n ==2:  # focus on ':' at the end.
```

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax problems: with spaces and the ":". Your code will work like this:

```
def fibonacci (n) :
  if n == 1  or n ==2:
    return 1
  return fibonacci (n-1)  + fibonacci(n-2)
for i in range (1,11):
  print (fibonacci (i))
```

Another example:

```
def fibonacci2(num):
  a = 1
  b = 0
  res = []
  temp=0
  while (num >= 0):
    temp = a
    a = a + b
    b = temp
    res.append(b)
    num -= 1
  return res
```

Comment: @AlexKaganovsky you are welcome! don't forget to mark the questiion if you liked it

Comment: I sent you mail on gmail can you response

Comment: Im trying to print only the value of fibonacci = 11 and it's failing i get no result           
 fibonacci (n) :
  if n == 1  or n ==2:
    return 1
  return fibonacci (n-1)  + fibonacci(n-2)
  print (fibonacci (11))